# Is it possible to bind form controls to VBA properties?

Tags: ms-access

I am currently updating an MS-Access legacy project. In a form I want to bind some controls to VBA properties (`Property Let` and `Property Get`), similar to the way it is done in WPF. Is this posssible? We are using Access 2007.

Answer (score 0):

The *ControlSource* of a control can be a function:

```
=MyFunctionReadingSomeProperty([SomeParameter])
```

so if you can manage to build such a function, the answer is Yes.

However, the function is read-only, so if you want to set a property, the function must be able to do that using one (or more) parameters.

If you omit the parameter:

```
=MyFunctionReadingSomeProperty()
```

the function will be called only once, when the form loads.